# How to add URL image as scss variable

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have following scss style. I have added bg color as variable & it is working fine. I need to add 'icons.png' also as variable.

```
 .home {
           @include themify($themes) {
               background: url(images/icons.png) themed('bgcolor');
           }
    }
```

How to add "icons.png" as veritable? like

background: url(images/**VARIABLENAME**) themed('bgcolor');

Comment: What is 'themed'?

Comment: And what does `$themes` var contain? What does `themify` mixin do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$image: 'icons.png';  
.home {
       @include themify($themes) {
           background: url(images/${$image}) themed('bgcolor');
       }
}
```